# Having trouble selecting radio buttons

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

So, basically this is pretty simple. I'm creating a tip calculator application that allows the user to enter a bunch of information on their meal/service and I'm supposed to calculate the results at the bottom in a text field next to the calculate button. The trouble I'm having is selecting only one radio button from the "Select Tip:" option. I have tried adding a RadioGroup widget to my application, but I don't know how to make my radio buttons comply with it nor do I know how to add the radio group in my application without affecting the size and positions of my current radio buttons. Here's a visual of what my application looks like: http://tinypic.com/r/yc46t/8

**MyActivity.java**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final EditText enteredFoodAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.foodAmount);
        final EditText enteredDrinkAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.drinkAmount);
        final EditText enteredTaxAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.taxAmount);
        final RadioButton tenSelected = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.tenPercent);
        final RadioButton fifteenSelected = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fifteenPercent);
        final RadioButton twentySelected = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.twentyPercent);
        final TextView displayedFoodAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theFoodAmount);
        final TextView displayedDrinkAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theDrinkAmount);
        final TextView displayedTaxAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theTaxAmount);
        final TextView displayedTipAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theTipAmount);
        final Button calculateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        final TextView displayedCalculation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.calculatedAmount);
        final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);

        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double food = Double.parseDouble(enteredFoodAmount.getText().toString());
                double drink = Double.parseDouble(enteredDrinkAmount.getText().toString());
                double tax = Double.parseDouble(enteredTaxAmount.getText().toString()) / 100.0;
                double tip;
                double calculation;

                if (tenSelected.isChecked()){
                    twentySelected.setChecked(false);
                    tip = 0.10;
                    displayedTipAmount.setText(Double.toString(tip * 100.0) + "%");

                    displayedFoodAmount.setText("$" + Double.toString(food));
                    displayedDrinkAmount.setText("$" + Double.toString(drink));
                    displayedTaxAmount.setText(Double.toString(tax * 100.0) + "%");

                    double myTax = (food + drink) * tax;
                    double myTip = (food + drink) * tip;
                    calculation = (food + drink) + myTax + myTip;
                    displayedCalculation.setText("$" + Double.toString(calculation));
                }
                else if (twentySelected.isChecked()){
                    tenSelected.setChecked(false);
                    tip = 0.20;
                    displayedTipAmount.setText(Double.toString(tip * 100.0) + "%");

                    displayedFoodAmount.setText("$" + Double.toString(food));
                    displayedDrinkAmount.setText("$" + Double.toString(drink));
                    displayedTaxAmount.setText(Double.toString(tax * 100.0) + "%");

                    double myTax = (food + drink) * tax;
                    double myTip = (food + drink) * tip;
                    calculation = (food + drink) + myTax + myTip;
                    displayedCalculation.setText("$" + Double.toString(calculation));
                }
                else if (fifteenSelected.isChecked()){

                    tip = 0.15;
                    displayedTipAmount.setText(Double.toString(tip * 100.0) + "%");

                    displayedFoodAmount.setText("$"+ Double.toString(food));
                    displayedDrinkAmount.setText("$" + Double.toString(drink));
                    displayedTaxAmount.setText(Double.toString(tax * 100.0) + "%");

                    double myTax = (food + drink) * tax;
                    double myTip = (food + drink) * tip;
                    calculation = (food + drink) + myTax + myTip;
                    displayedCalculation.setText("$" + Double.toString(calculation));
                }
```

**activity_my.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layoutt">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/food_total"
        android:id="@+id/foodTotal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/drink_total"
        android:id="@+id/drinkTotal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodTotal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/foodAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/drinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drinkTotal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/foodAmount"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/foodAmount"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ten_percent"
        android:id="@+id/tenPercent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drinkTotal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fifteenPercent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drinkTotal"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fifteen_percent"
        android:id="@+id/fifteenPercent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drinkTotal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tenPercent"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tenPercent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drinkTotal"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/twenty_percent"
        android:id="@+id/twentyPercent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drinkTotal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fifteenPercent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fifteenPercent"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fifteenPercent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drinkTotal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/calculatedAmount"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/drinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calculate"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Total Tax"
        android:id="@+id/tax"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/taxAmount"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tax"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/drinkAmount"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/select_tip"
        android:id="@+id/selectTip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tenPercent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/the_food"
        android:id="@+id/theFood"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twentyPercent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/the_drink"
        android:id="@+id/theDrink"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theFood"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/the_tax"
        android:id="@+id/theTax"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theFood"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twentyPercent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/twentyPercent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/the_tip"
        android:id="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/twentyPercent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theDrink"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/theTax"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/theTax"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twentyPercent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/theFoodAmount"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/calculatedAmount"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calculatedAmount"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calculatedAmount"
        android:text="--"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theFood"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/theDrinkAmount"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/theDrinkAmount"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="--"
        android:id="@+id/theDrinkAmount"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theDrink"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theDrink"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theDrink"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="--"
        android:id="@+id/theTaxAmount"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theTax"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theTax"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theTax"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="--"
        android:id="@+id/theTipAmount"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calculatedAmount"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calculatedAmount"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tenPercent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectTip"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/selectTip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/theFood"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/theTip"
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RadioButtons have to be children inside of the RadioGroup.

```
<RelativeLayout ... >

    <!-- some views -->

    <RadioGroup ... >
        <RadioButton ... />

        <RadioButton ... />

        <RadioButton ... />
    </RadioGroup>

    <!-- more views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know how I could make them children without affecting the positions they are in?

Comment: You can move the RadioGroup. My answer does not concern anything visual, only hierarchical.